# Where am I likely to find a hidden NM-to-K&T splice?

Tags: wiring, knob-and-tube, splices

I am trying to understand electrical work that was done on my house before I bought it. It's a 1922 build with a lot of original knob and tube wiring. What follows are some details, but the question is summarized at the end.

I have mapped out all the circuits and already found a lot of sloppy / illegal work like MWBCs on untied breakers, jumpers from neutral to ground in outlets to fool plugin testers, low voltage boxes used for 120v receptacles, #14 wire on 20a breakers, you name it.

The circuit I'm looking at now powers the entire upstairs as one half of a MWBC. At the panel it is connected with a single NM cable which runs all the way across the basement ceiling before going up through a hole in the subfloor and presumably into an exterior wall. This circuit doesn't power anything downstairs, but there is a large drywall patch (approx 24" x 18") on that wall above that point on the first floor. There is a nearby (~6 ft away) receptacle on a different circuit.

The receptacles and fixtures upstairs are all still on fabric insulated wires except in the bathroom, which was recently renovated. Using a scope I was able to trace the new cable from the bathroom receptacle to a new stud inside the wall. The stud has a hole in it, drilled with a spade bit, and the direction of the hole is coming *into* the stud bay where the receptacle resides. There are no obvious wall patches on the other side of that stud -- and only about 2 feet of wall to check, as it quickly runs into a doorway. This wall is interior to the house, and not at all convenient to the first floor patch I mentioned above.

There are no modern splices in the attic at all that I can find, and I've looked pretty extensively. I've opened every junction box on the second floor and none of them contains a splice between NM and K&T. I would really like to know where they made these connections, because all evidence suggests they did a bad job. Before I start opening up walls, I'm hoping someone might have experience with scenarios like this.

To summarize: Where am I likely to find the splice from new wiring at the panel to old knob and tube wiring, given that it's hidden, and maybe deliberately?

Comment: I am not sure exactly how serious or facetious I am being here, but based on your description of how poorly things in general have been done, you are most likely to find these splices using tape without junction boxes in arbitrary stud bays throughout the walls of the house.     The one feeding upstairs is almost certainly behind the patch in the first floor wall.  Is the upstairs bathroom still on that same circuit?  They didn't run a cable to the panel for the renovation?  If so .. the splice is in a bathroom wall somewhere.  You'll never find it.

Comment: The big patch might be it if the patcher went with a bigger drywall patch is as easy as a small patch.  This does sound like a job for an camera that uses small holes.

Comment: Sounds more like a remove-all-the-drywall and redo everything kind of a job...

Comment: The bad news first: your description of so many known problems suggests many hidden ones as well.  It may be time to bite the bullet and have the house rewired.  The good news, and this is truly important, is that you will have done this before the fire rather than after.  Even a single small fire can damage extensively with its smoke, not to mention firefighters chopping holes in walls and water damage.  And trigger citations from building inspectors for unrelated items. (voice of experience here)

Comment: And have any insurance claim denied for not being in code.

Comment: New wiring will also improve your standing with your insurance company.

Comment: One last thought — purely opinion based. I downgraded all my breakers from 20 to 15A in a house that still had mysterious k+t… the idea was that faults would trip sooner. Ymmv.